# Jest Snapshot testing on Gutenberg React Custom Blocks

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, wordpress-gutenberg, snapshot-testing

I tried to set up a working Jest environment inside a Wordpress plugin.
Gutenberg blocks are split between an edit.jsx component and a save.jsx component.
My issue stands when I try to create a snapshot test for such blocks.

For example I tried to create a test file like so:

```
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import edit from '../../blocks/myblock/edit.jsx';

it('comparing with block snapshot', () => {
    const tree = renderer
        .create(<edit/>)
        .toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

but the snapshot that Jest creates is this one

```
exports[`comparing with block snapshot 1`] = `<edit />`;
```

the block has a return statement with much HTML inside.

How do I make jest render all the HTML in edit.jsx?
Why am I getting  only that `<edit />` tag in the snapshot?